# После логина на web-сервер получаем повторный запрос на авторизацию

Tags: c#, html

Необходимо залогиниться на сайт по HTTP и получить страницу, доступ к которой требует предварительной авторизации. Логин, якобы, проходит, но сервер продолжает отдавать форму авторизации.

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    private CookieContainer cookie = new CookieContainer();

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = cookie;
        }
        return request;
    }
}

void o5()
    {
        CookieAwareWebClient client = new CookieAwareWebClient();
        client.BaseAddress = @"http://00.00.00.000:0000/accounts/login/?next=/about/";
        var loginData = new NameValueCollection();
        loginData.Add("login", "name");
        loginData.Add("password", "pass123");
        client.UploadValues("login.php", "POST", loginData);

        string htmlSource = client.DownloadString("index.php");
        htmlSource += "\n" + htmlSource.Length;


        string s2 = client.DownloadString(@"http://00.00.00.000:0000/filebrowser/view//EDW_UAT/staging/landing/.ctl/001/0002/000097/0001/001_0002_000097_A_20170515000000_20170515235959_0001_0000_ADJUSTMENTS.ctl");
        s2 += "\n" + htmlSource.Length;

        tb1.Text += htmlSource;
        tb2.Text += s2;
    }
```

По идее `tb1` должен содержать страницу после логина и она там есть. А `tb2` должен получить данные которые содержатся на 2 странице, но вместо этого возвращается код страницы авторизации, как если бы я обратился без куки.

Comment: Похоже Вы не дожидаетесь окончания первого запроса: для проверки просто вставьте delay (Thread.Sleep)

Comment: Попробовал не помогло. Может кто скинет другой пример повторной авторизации

Comment: Возьмите любой отладчик http (Fiddler, например), и проверьте, уходит ли авторизационная кука при при втором запросе. Сравните с тем же самым действием при работе через браузер. Может быть вы на какую-то защиту от CSRF нарываетесь, которая требует дополнительных заголовков или кук.